# Is there any trouble google play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I have published four applications on 1 july. These applications don't appear Google play store
in the 250 applications but the number of downloads is increasing for these applications.

I have searched this issue and some people experienced this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue with my app, whose name is quite generic. 
No wonder, when only the generic name is typed, those apps with thousands of downloads appeared much earlier than my app. Fortunately, after a few months, with increasing downloads and more ratings, the rank of my app increased. Now when the most generic name is given, my app is #104. (Update Oct 2014: with a lot more downloads, now my app is #1 in the result it.)

I think the problem is kinda like a competition between newly-emerged apps and the older, popular apps. There shouldn't be any easy trick (if there were, then every developer would use it and nothing would change.)

Here's a pretty good article I found titled "How Does Google Play Rank Mobile Apps". Hope you find it useful

https://getappcase.com/blog/app-stores/how-does-google-play-rank-mobile-apps

You'll see that downloads, app quality, country, ratings and comments all contribute to the ranking of an app.

My opinion/suggestion:

- select a unique name, at least a name that's not too generic or cliched. Find a few keywords you'd like your app to be searched.
- add good descriptions (my app can be top 3 hit if certain keywords are provided). Repeat your keywords in the description. Repeat.
- be patient. It'll take time ... even updating your description will take google a considerable amount of time to take effect, let alone the play store ranking.
- get more downloads and positive ratings, etc. More downloads --> higher ranking.